# AngularJS $http reading JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

How can i display data from an array of JSON data returned from the server in AngularJS? This is what i have, and for some reason i cannot display any data on my html page:

```
<script>
     function placesCtrl($scope, $http) {

          $http.get("http://somedomain/api/places_JSON.php")
          .success(function(response){
               $scope.names = response;
           });
          $scope.display = $scope.names[2].City;
      }
</script>
```

The JSON data that the $http.get is returning looks something like this:

```
[{City: "Berlin", Country: "Germany"},
{City: "Portland", Country: "USA"},
{City: "Barcelona", Country: "Spain"},
{City: "Paris", Country: "France"},
{City: "Cowes", Country: "UK"}]
```

Then the HTML code looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="placesCtrl">

<p> {{display}}</p>
</div>
```

So instead of displaying "Barcelona" as the result, it just displays {{display}}.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, post a demo to reproduce the issue. Try http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `success` callback is called after you set the scope variable. Move the variable assignment inside your callback function, and you should be fine.

Also, as ryeballar points out, it's highly recommended that you as you register an application in the `ng-app` directive. See [the tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) for details. Although you don't need it for a simple example like this, it will make your life much, much easier as you add more components.

Comment: I think that wouldn't solve the problem. Displaying the curly brackets mean Angular hasn't worked properly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. hgoebl's answer is also required

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos, I think it will. the `{{display}}` output suggests that a problem may have occurred in the angular lifecycle. `$scope.names[2].City` will cause an error since `$scope.names` did not exist yet. @Jason, it is not necessary to name an `ng-app`. Try it in a plunker and it would still work. But I agree that it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your Controller. Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('placesCtrl', ['$http','$scope', function($http, $scope) {
    $http.get("http://somedomain/api/places_JSON.php")
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.names = response;
    });
    $scope.display = $scope.names[2].City;
}]);
```

And edit your html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="placesCtrl">
```

Comment: That's version dependent.  In the 1.2.x branch, a global function could be used as controller without registering it (that was a new feature over 1.0.x IIRC).  Only recently in the 1.3.x experimental branch, this behavior was removed again: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018